# Nginx configuration with Frontend and Backed applications in the same server, failes with Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I deployed 2 applications in a Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS server,
a backend FastAPI service, and a frontend Reactjs application.
The backend runs on `http://localhost:8000,` and it serves  APIs at `/api/v1`
The frontend runs on `http://localhost:3000` and can locally reach the backend APIs.

My goal is to access the frontend application from a `web.mydomain.com,` having the reactjs application reach the APIs served locally in the same server.
Nginx should act as a reverse-proxy in a scenario like this.

However, something is not correct in my configuration and I am currently facing the following errors when I access the application at `http://web.mydomain.com`

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/login/access_token' from origin 'http://web.mydomain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`.
```

#### System conf

```
node -v
v18.19.1
```

```
npm list 
── @emotion/cache@11.10.7
├── @emotion/react@11.10.6
├── @emotion/styled@11.10.6
├── @material-ui/core@4.12.4
├── @material-ui/icons@4.11.3
├── @mui/icons-material@5.11.16
├── @mui/joy@5.0.0-beta.19
├── @mui/material@5.12.0
├── @mui/styled-engine@5.12.0
├── @mui/styles@5.15.3
├── @mui/x-charts@6.18.4
├── @mui/x-date-pickers@6.18.6
├── @tanstack/react-query@5.18.1
├── @testing-library/jest-dom@5.16.5
├── @testing-library/react@14.0.0
├── @testing-library/user-event@14.4.3
├── axios@1.6.2
├── chroma-js@2.4.2
├── dayjs@1.11.10
├── dotenv@16.4.4
├── flatpickr@4.6.13
├── http-proxy-middleware@2.0.6
├── material-react-table@2.10.0
├── material-table@2.0.5
├── material-ui-dropzone@3.5.0
├── process@0.11.10
├── prop-types@15.8.1
├── react-copy-to-clipboard@5.1.0
├── react-countup@6.4.2
├── react-dom@18.2.0
├── react-flatpickr@3.10.13
├── react-router-dom@6.10.0
├── react-scripts@5.0.1
├── react-syntax-highlighter@15.5.0
├── react@18.2.0
├── simple-react-lightbox@3.6.9-0
└── web-vitals@3.3.1
```

```
Python 3.10.5
```

```
nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

#### What I have done so far:

My initial and basic configuration was

```
upstream backend {
      server localhost:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        charset utf-8;
        server_name  web.mydomain.com;

        root   /var/www/reactjs_frontend/build;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        gzip on;
        gzip_types text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/json;

        # backend urls
        location ~ ^/(admin|api|media) {
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://backend;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }

        # static files
        location /static {
            alias /var/www/reactjs_frontend/build/static/;
        }

        # frontend
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
}
```

The application is loaded at `http://web.mydomain.com,` but when I try to access the backend's API, let's say `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/login/access_token` as a result of filling the login form, the following issue occurs:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/login/access_token' from origin 'http://web.mydomain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`.
```

After browsing through a few similar issues, such as

- [Wildfly for backend and NGINX for frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71407306/wildfly-for-backend-and-nginx-for-frontend)
- [Nginx reverse proxy to frontend and backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64911879/nginx-reverse-proxy-to-frontend-and-backend)
- [Nginx 502 Bad Gateway error when call api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55857412/nginx-502-bad-gateway-error-when-call-api)
- [has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69542810/has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-the-request-client-is-not-a-secure-context-and)

and a few more, I changed my configuration, applying the following changes,  but without any luck. The issue is still occurring.

This is my current configuration:

```
upstream backend {
            server localhost:8000;
        }

server {
        listen *:80;
        server_name web.mydomain.com;
        root /var/www/reactjs_frontend/build;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/reactjs_access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/reactjs_error.log;

        location / {

                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  '*' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                    
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
                add_header    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Request-Private-Network' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Private-Networl' 'true';
                
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

                if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS' ) {

                        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                        add_header 'Content-Type' 'application/json;';
                        return 204;

                }
                if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';

                }
                if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                       add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';

                }
                proxy_pass_request_headers      on;

        }
        location /api/v1/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/api/v1/;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header authorization $http_authorization;
                proxy_pass_request_headers on;
                proxy_no_cache $cookie_nocache $arg_nocache$arg_comment;
                proxy_no_cache $http_pragma     $http_authorization;
                proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_nocache $arg_nocache $arg_comment;

                if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {

                    #
                    # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
                    #
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  'http://localhost:3000' always;
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD' always;
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept' always;
                    add_header  'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
                    return 204;
                }

                if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  'http://localhost:3000' always;
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD' always;
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept' always;
                    add_header    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
                }
                if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  'http://localhost:3000' always;
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD' always;
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept' always;
                    add_header    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;

                }


        }
}
```

To add more info about the context, this is the `index.html` generated by `rpm run build`

```html
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.png"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#1A73E8"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-icon.png"/><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/><title>MyApp</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900|Roboto+Slab:400,700"/><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet"/><script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/42d5adcbca.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script defer="defer" data-site="YOUR_DOMAIN_HERE" src="https://api.nepcha.com/js/nepcha-analytics.js"></script><script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.13416a3b.js"></script><link href="/static/css/main.be921a39.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div></body></html>
```

### Update

I have also tried the following very common configuration

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/reactjs_frontend/build;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name web.mydomain.com;
        location / {
                # serve static frontend first
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
        # location ~*^/(api|posts|products) {
        location /api {

                if ($request_method = OPTION) {
                        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin web.mydomain.com;
                        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
                        add_header Content-Length 0;
                        return 204;
                }
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin web.mydomain.com;
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
}
```

without any luck.

I have also add to the reactjs application the following `http-proxy-middleware` in the `webpack.config.js`

```
const {createProxyMiddleware} = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
      fallback: { process: require.resolve('process/browser') },
    },
    plugins: [
      new createProxyMiddleware({
        target:"http://localhost:8000",
        changeOrigin: true,
      })
    ],
  };
```

### UPDATE REFLECTING THE ANSWER - FIX

As for this clear [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78036286/1684560), the problem was not in the configuration.
Instead of trying to have the react app reach the backend running on localhost, I have to access it available from `http://web.mydomain.com/api/v1/`
The following configuration exposes the backend on `http://web.mydomain.com/api/v1/`
The reactjs now, instead of using `http://localhost:8000`, it uses `http://web.mydomain.com/api/v1/` and everything works as expected.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/reactjs_frontend/build;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name web.mydomain.com;
        location / {
                # serve static frontend first
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;

        }
        location /api/v1/ {
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE';
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse-proxy receives requests from clients and forwards them to the appropriate application, but it only works when you are actually hitting the endpoint. In your case, you are trying to hit a **local** endpoint from your **remote** frontend application which is the main issue.

Your frontend and backend are hosted on the same server and your subdomain `web.mydomain.com` is linked to the server. As per your nginx config, path `/` serves your frontend and `/api/v1/*` serves your backend. This is known as **path-based routing**. When you hit `https://web.mydomain.com/`, your reverse-proxy (nginx in this case) knows that it has to serve the frontend application and it provides the necessary files (HTML, CSS, JS, and other assets). Now onwards, everything that's happening in the web app, is taking place in the on your browser only. So, when your web application hits `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/` from your browser, it is trying to access the localhost of that machine and not the one from the server.

To access the backend, you need to hit `https://web.mydomain.com/api/v1/*`.
The error you got indicates that you are trying to access private network resources which is blocked by most of the browsers by default. Similar issue you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66534759/cors-error-on-request-to-localhost-dev-server-from-remote-site) as well.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So, if I got it right, one solution would be to expose the backend's APIs and have the reactjs app use them instead of trying to reach localhost.

Comment: Yes, if your backend's API is exposed then it's all good to go. For example, you have deployed your frontend and backend on the same AWS EC2 server and your domain is mapped to your server. You have a *nginx reverse-proxy* running on that EC2 machine which will perform `path-based routing` as explained above. This might not be a very ideal scenario but I hope it makes my point clear.

Comment: Yes, it does make sense. It's probably not the ideal scenario.  I should probably move everything to k8s for a better solution.

Comment: If you don't have a lot of microservices, ECS could work fine as well plus it's not very complicated if you already know about containerization. Else, you can stick to EC2s for the time being